# Python: Inner Class

Tags: python, inner-classes

I am trying to create a json string from a class and I defined my class as follows:

```
import json
import ast
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import time

class OuterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Header = None
        self.Body = None

    class Header:
        def __init__(self, ID = None, Name = None):
            self.ID =  ID
            self.Name = Name 

    class Body:
        def __init__(self, DateTime=None, Display=None):
            self.DateTime = DateTime
            self.Display = Display

def current_time_by_timezone(timezone_input):
    return datetime.now(pytz.timezone(timezone_input))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    response = OuterClass()
    header = response.Header('123', 'Some Name')
    body = response.Body(current_time_by_timezone('US/Central'), 'NOT VALID')
    print(json.dumps(response.__dict__))
```

I'm getting an error 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable'. Is it because I'm setting the Header and Body in the OuterClass definition myself to None?

Comment: you're getting the error where? On what line?

Comment: Short answer: yes. More precisely, it is set to None when you initialize the class

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk: I'm getting error on the line: header=response('123', 'Some Name')

Comment: response.Header is None because you set it to None, yes. Try just Header(...) or OuterClass.Header(...)

Comment: As pointed by @luk2302, what do you expect `self.Header = None;  self.Body = None` to accomplish?

Comment: @PM77-1: I want the Header and Body to be nested classes of the OuterClass and I wnat to be able to assign the Header and Body later in my code to my OuterClass.

Comment: @luk2302: I'm getting the error: AttributeError: class OuterClass has no attribute 'Header'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is these lines:

```
    self.Header = None
    self.Body = None
```

These create instance variables named `Header` and `Body` on every instance of `OuterClass`, so you can never access the class variables (the nested classes) via an instance, only via `OuterClass` itself.

It's not very clear what your intention is with this data structure. Defining a class inside another class doesn't do anything special in Python (by default, you could probably *make* there be special behavior with special effort, like using a metaclass that makes the inner classes into descriptors). Generally though, there's no implied relationship between the classes.

If you want your `OuterClass` to create instances of the other two classes, you can do that without nesting their definitions. Just put the class definitions at top level and write a method that creates an instance at an appropriate time and does something useful with it (like binding it to an instance variable).

You might want something like:

```
def Header:
   ...

def Response:
   def __init__(self):
       self.header = None

   def make_header(self, *args):
       self.header = Header(*args)
       return self.header
```

You could keep the classes nested as long as you don't expect that to mean anything special, just be sure that you don't use the class name as an instance variable, or you'll shadow the name of the nested class (a capitalization difference, like `self.header` vs `self.Header` could be enough).